# Flutter iOS App Store Connect require upload iPad Screenshots

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I only want my App to available on iPhone. This is what I setup in XCode:

[image]

And in my `project.pbxproj` I set all `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1;`

But still when I upload my `build` to AppStore Connect it tells me to upload iPad Screenshots:

[image]

What am I missing here? Apple always rejects me because of the missing screenshots.. I only want iPhone support, not iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i saw your version 1.1.2, I think you uploaded before right? Did you upload app with support for both iPhone and iPad before? **If you did once** then store needs ipad screenshots even if you remove(uncheck) ipad and release new version.

Comment: that was actually it... Oh man. it is frighting how little work apple puts into app store connect...